# OpenCart upgrade 1.5.6. to 2.3.0.2

Tags: php, opencart, opencart2.x

I upgrade OpenCart from `1.5.6` to `2.3.0.2` it was upgrade successfully  and admin login work good but store front page not working, it's getting error.

The example.com page isn’t working

> example.com is currently unable to handle this request.
>
> `HTTP ERROR 500`

Comment: Http error 500 could mean anything, you need to check the error logs... Hopefully there isn't too much wrong, but I wouldn't imagine OpenCart is something you can easily upgrade, especially from 1.5.* to 2.* - all your plugins & templates are probably not compatible... Best thing - if it's not something simple - may be to revert to the backup, and have a web developer do the upgrade properly.

Answer (score 0):

Try to :

1. Edit your `.htaccess` file (just insert # before Options)
2. Reinstall vqmod
3. Read error log

Comment: I will disagree. First of all when you get `500 Internal server error` you should `read error log`. This should not be last try.

Comment: its not satisfactory answer

Answer (score 0):

I got the following response when I asked the OpenCart team how to resolve this issue:

> Thank you for your enquiry.
>
> Please don't upgrade your store on your own. You will have a lot of
>   errors. Try the qphoria upgrade service. He is one of our top
>   developer.
>   http://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=extension/extension/info&extension_id=20437&filter_search=upgrade
>
> Best Wishes, John OpenCart Team